# Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Cygwin

Tags: path, cygwin

I am following the tutorial : http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html

when I reach the part where I am supposed to set the library path :

Unix or Linux:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Windows NT/2000/95:

```
set PATH=%path%;
```

Neither of these work in cygwin. I keep getting an error when trying to run my program.

Comment: It looks like pwd was supposed to be in backticks, but the formatting rendered it as code instead.

Answer (score 18):

Cygwin doesn't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, it looks for shared libraries in `PATH`, so try:

```
export PATH=`pwd`:$PATH
```

That will add the current directory to the front of the PATH.

Comment: Indeed, `Cygwin` doesn't honor `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in certain specific matters. Also, you have to explicitly name your dynamic library to have the `*.dll` extension otherwise things won't work. Here is demo evidence https://asciinema.org/a/LzPWhdhu7ZU2Ub9lsUfZHvZq5

Comment: for GMP (-lgmp) i had to add -L/usr/local/lib none of the above worked

Comment: @colinlamarre looks like you are talking about just getting the program to link, which is a completely different problem. This question and answer is about getting it to run, after you've already linked successfully.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely ha yes no wonder it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Is that

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)
```

and you just messed up the html, or are you really running:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=pwd
```

If the latter, try adding the $() to get the current working directory into the path.  Also, you can

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to ensure it contains what you want.   You might consider doing

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$(pwd)
```

to avoid discarding previous contents of the path.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clear that the OP was doing `\`pwd\`` which is equivalent to `$(pwd)`

Comment: In `Cygwin`, the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not operative to certain matters pertaining to finding the accompanying dynamic library.